# How can I call the find query after successful update query with ReactiveMongo and akka, getting None.get exception

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have two queries in my code

1st one is `update` query

```
var  modifier = BSONDocument("$set" -> BSONDocument("client_id" -> client_id,
          "access_token" -> access_token,
          "refresh_token" ->refresh_token,
          "inserted_date" -> inserted_date))
        var selecter = BSONDocument("$and" -> BSONArray(BSONDocument("account_id" -> account_id), BSONDocument("refresh_token" -> object.refreshToken)))

 tokensCollection.update(selecter, modifier)
```

2nd one is `find` query

```
 var query = BSONDocument("$and" -> BSONArray(BSONDocument("account_id" -> account_id), BSONDocument("refresh_token" -> refresh_token)))

    val resp = tokensCollection.find(query).one[AccessTokens]
    var result = Await.result(resp, 15 seconds)
    result.get
```

my 2nd one `find` query is executed before the 1st query `update`.I got the issue

```
method have exception:java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
```

how can I call the find query after successful update of 1st query

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem... What's your scenario? You update some data and then you want to retrieve it but you don't get any result? Or do you want to load something first and then update it?

Comment: update some data and then you want to retrieve it but I didn't get any result. `Update` query takes time and before `update` query `find` query executed.It is because update takes more time than find query.

Comment: Using unsafe `.get` is highly discouraged, rather compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that your `tokensCollection.update()` call will also return a `Future[_]` of some kind. Only when that `Future` completes will your result be guaranteed to be available in the database.

You can serialize the two like this:

```
val resp = tokensCollection.update(s, m).flatMap(_ => tokensCollection.find(query))
```

or, using a `for` comprehension:

```
for {
  _ <- tokensCollection.update(s, m)
  q <- tokensCollection.find(query)
} yield q
```

Note that `Await` is not something that you should use in production; rather, return `Future`s everywhere and call `map` on the final result. However, if you're just playing around, it can be useful for debugging.

Comment: I have used like `var resp = tokensCollection.update(selecter, modifier).flatMap(_ => tokensCollection.find(findQuery).one[AccessTokens])
      var result = Await.result(resp, 15 seconds)
      result.get` this one also sometimes returned exception

Comment: `Future`s can fail. You will need to handle the Exception in a way that makes sense for your application.

Comment: yes, am handling exceptions. Is there any possibility my code performance will increase if I use this
 `tokensCollection.remove(selecter)
      var resp = tokensCollection.insert(accessTokensInfo).flatMap(_ => tokensCollection.find(findQuery).one[AccessTokens])
  `

Comment: You'd have the same problem as before; `remove` returns a `Future` that needs to complete first. Even if you did chain it properly (either with `flatMap` or a `for` comprehension), I highly doubt that would help, but as always when talking about performance: benchmarking is the only valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is because update takes more time than find query.You must serialise the query.You have to wait for the response from the update query and than after that execute the find query.

Comment: can you please suggest how to achieve this. I have used below code or getting response `val resp = tokensCollection.find(query).one[AccessTokens]
    var result = Await.result(resp, 15 seconds)`